# Accessing a specific string Python List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in python and I am trying to print out the list's contents that have Brooklyn in it. I am running into a wall of somewhat and I am not sure how to go about getting this answer. Can someone help me?

```
list_woo=[]

 list_woo[0] = ['BROOKLYN', 'PETIT LARCENY OF MOTOR VEHICLE']
 list_woo[1] = ['BROOKLYN', 'OFFENSES AGAINST PUBLIC ADMINI']
 list_woo[2] = ['MANHATTAN', 'ASSAULT 3 & RELATED OFFENSES']
 list_woo[3] = ['BROOKLYN', 'ROBBERY']
```

if 'BROOKLYN' is in list_woo

Print out all contents that have Brooklyn in it, and the corresponding crimes. So the only one that should not show is MANHATTAN when you print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
list_woo=[]

list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'PETIT LARCENY OF MOTOR VEHICLE'])
list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'OFFENSES AGAINST PUBLIC ADMINI'])
list_woo.append(['MANHATTAN', 'ASSAULT 3 & RELATED OFFENSES'])
list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'ROBBERY'])

for borough, crime in list_woo:
    if borough == 'BROOKLYN':
        print([borough, crime])
```

Your original code won't work because it initializes `list_woo` to be an empty list with no items and then attempts to update items at specific indices. Instead, you must either use `append()` to "grow" the list as in this answer or initialize using something like `list_woo = [None] * 4` so that you allocate in advance the space necessary to place items at indices `0` through `3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  list_woo=[['BROOKLYN', 'PETIT LARCENY OF MOTOR VEHICLE'],
      ['BROOKLYN', 'OFFENSES AGAINST PUBLIC ADMINI'],
      ['MANHATTAN', 'ASSAULT 3 & RELATED OFFENSES'],
      ['BROOKLYN', 'ROBBERY']]

   # Solution 1
   for i in range(len(list_woo)):
      if list_woo[i][0]=='BROOKLYN':
          print(list_woo[i][1])

   import numpy as np

   # Solution 2
   array_woo = np.array(list_woo)
   indexArr = np.argwhere(array_woo == 'BROOKLYN')
   for i in indexArr:
     print(array_woo[i[0],1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not quite sure if this is what you want, but you can use filter, and modify this code to get the desired behavior:

```
list_woo=[]

list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'PETIT LARCENY OF MOTOR VEHICLE'])
list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'OFFENSES AGAINST PUBLIC ADMINI'])
list_woo.append(['MANHATTAN', 'ASSAULT 3 & RELATED OFFENSES'])
list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'ROBBERY'])

filtered_list = filter(lambda element: 'BROOKLYN' in element[0], list_woo)

for val in filtered_list:
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprex lists for get that.

```py
list_woo = []

list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'PETIT LARCENY OF MOTOR VEHICLE'])
list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'OFFENSES AGAINST PUBLIC ADMINI'])
list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'ASSAULT 3 & RELATED OFFENSES'])
list_woo.append(['BROOKLYN', 'ROBBERY'])


print(*[element for element in list_woo if element[0] == 'BROOKLYN'], sep='\n')
```